While using TestLab getting 'Unused text input: no resource name matched the regex "mobilenumber"'
I was checking performance of app using Firebase Test lab. In Robo directives (optional).. i have selected Resource action 'Enter Text' and in resource name given 'mobilenumber'. After executing(Starting) Test, In result it is giving Unused text input: no resource name matched the regex "mobilenumber"'. I checked property of same field using appium inspector its showing the resource id as "mobilenumber"
<TextInput
  style={styles.mobile_no_text_input}
  placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  id="mobilenumber"
  testID="mobilenumber"
  returnKeyType="done"
/>

This is Code used by developer.
